# Why does my react app say "Cannot GET /route", if the user changes browsers?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, npm, react-router

I have a React app using React-Router and Express. I added a new route, which accepts an encrypted private key and allows a user to auto-login, via a link to their email inbox.

Here is the route:

```
<PublicRoute path="/loader/:user_key" component={Loader} />
```

`{Loader}` is a React component with a componentWillMount() function, which parses the URL, grabs the "`user_key`", authenticates the user, creates a cookie, and redirects them to a private "/home" route.

The link works great -- *as long as the user has already logged into the app previously from the **same** browser*. However, if the user created their account on one browser (eg laptop) and opens the email link from a different browser (eg mobile phone), the browser returns

> "Cannot GET /loader/..."

Do you have any suggestions? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is the server.js file (containing the key express logic)

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const expressValidator = require("express-validator");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongodb-session")(session);
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("./config/passport/index.js");
const routes = require("./routes/index.js");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const path = require("path");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const MONGODB_URI =
  process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost:27017/sonar";
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

//Parse application /x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Server instance
const server = http.createServer(app);

//Cronjobs
const cronjob = require("./cronjob.js");

// -------------------------- Sessions -----------------------------

//Initiate sessions
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "Secret",
    store: new MongoStore({ uri: MONGODB_URI, collection: "sessions" }),
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 3*60*60*1000 // In milliseconds
    }
  })
);

//Initialize passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // will call the deserializeUser

// --------------------- Backend Validation---------------------------

//This validates and sanitizes strings
app.use(
  expressValidator({
    errorFormatter: (param, msg, value) => {
      const namespace = param.split("."),
        root = namespace.shift(),
        formParam = root;

      while (namespace.length) {
        formParam += "[" + namespace.shift() + "]";
      }
      return {
        param: formParam,
        msg: msg,
        value: value
      };
    }
  })
);

// -------------------------- Routes -----------------------------

//Sets static assets path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/build")));

//Sets route to index
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  // console.log("Is this firing? '/' ")
  res.sendFile(__dirname, "/index.html");
});

//Setting up routes in app
app.use(routes);

// -------------------------- MongoDB -----------------------------

// Connect to the Mongo DB
mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Connection established to", MONGODB_URI);
  }
});

const db = mongoose.connection;

// Show any mongoose errors
db.on("error", error => {
  console.log("Mongoose Error: ", error);
});

// Once logged in to the db through mongoose, log a success message
db.once("open", () => {
  console.log("Mongoose connection successful.");
});

// -------------------------- Listen -----------------------------

// Start the API server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("App listening on PORT " + PORT);
});
```

**EDIT #2**

The issue seems to be in loading React-Router, once the `server.js` returns the `index.html` file. Adding the `index.html` file for reference:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-132577862-1"></script>

    <!-- Google Analytics -->
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'UA-132577862-1');
    </script>

    <!-- This deactivates browser navigation button: "Back" -->
    <script type="text/javascript" >
       function preventBack(){window.history.forward();}
        setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
        window.onunload=function(){null};
    </script>

    <!-- Stripe checkout -->
    <!-- <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script> -->

    <!-- React Script -->
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    <!-- <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"> -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="profilePicture/infinity_preloader.gif">

    <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Moment.js (I don't think this is necessary - can delete?) -->
    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script> -->

    <!-- This is the IE ES6 script work around -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=default,Array.prototype.includes"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.5/bluebird.min.js"></script>


    <!-- iPhone PWA icon -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="profilePicture/dummy_profile_Pic2.png"> 

    <!-- iPhone splash screens -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="profilePicture/dummy_profile_Pic2.png" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="profilePicture/dummy_profile_Pic2.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="profilePicture/dummy_profile_Pic2.png" media="(device-width: 621px) and (device-height: 1104px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="profilePicture/dummy_profile_Pic2.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="profilePicture/dummy_profile_Pic2.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="profilePicture/dummy_profile_Pic2.png" media="(device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="profilePicture/dummy_profile_Pic2.png" media="(device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata|Lato|Nunito|Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Cratic | The Culture Builder</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root" ></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A few questions here, is your app using any form of `local storage` or other PWA features? And, can you post your main `express` app file? It's important to redirect all requests to `index.html` so that react-router can take over and render the correct components.

Comment: To be more specific, it's important with react-router and express to function correctly together that you direct api requests from react to a handler through express, but route requests (meant for react-router) to index.html - this allows react router to take over and show the right content on the front end.

Comment: @MikeAbeln - I added the `server.js` file. And I use `local storage` to handle private routing, with cookies. All authorization is done using `passport-local` strategy. However, the "cannot GET/" error seems to happen before authorization begins.

Answer (score 0):

In your **server.js** express file add a wildcard route that catches any routes that may be unmatched and return with the `index.html` file, this allows `react-router` to take over and route on the front end:

```
...

// -------------------------- Routes -----------------------------

//Sets static assets path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/build")));

//Sets route to index
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  // console.log("Is this firing? '/' ")
  res.sendFile(__dirname, "/index.html");
});

//Setting up routes in app
app.use(routes);

// WILDCARD ROUTE HANDLER
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname, "/index.html");
};

...
```

Here is the full **server.js** file:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const expressValidator = require("express-validator");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongodb-session")(session);
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("./config/passport/index.js");
const routes = require("./routes/index.js");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const path = require("path");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const MONGODB_URI =
  process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost:27017/sonar";
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

//Parse application /x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Server instance
const server = http.createServer(app);

//Cronjobs
const cronjob = require("./cronjob.js");

// -------------------------- Sessions -----------------------------

//Initiate sessions
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "Secret",
    store: new MongoStore({ uri: MONGODB_URI, collection: "sessions" }),
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 3*60*60*1000 // In milliseconds
    }
  })
);

//Initialize passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // will call the deserializeUser

// --------------------- Backend Validation---------------------------

//This validates and sanitizes strings
app.use(
  expressValidator({
    errorFormatter: (param, msg, value) => {
      const namespace = param.split("."),
        root = namespace.shift(),
        formParam = root;

      while (namespace.length) {
        formParam += "[" + namespace.shift() + "]";
      }
      return {
        param: formParam,
        msg: msg,
        value: value
      };
    }
  })
);

// -------------------------- Routes -----------------------------

//Sets static assets path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/build")));

//Sets route to index
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  // console.log("Is this firing? '/' ")
  res.sendFile(__dirname, "/index.html");
});

//Setting up routes in app
app.use(routes);

// WILDCARD ROUTE HANDLER
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname, "index.html");
}

// -------------------------- MongoDB -----------------------------

// Connect to the Mongo DB
mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Connection established to", MONGODB_URI);
  }
});

const db = mongoose.connection;

// Show any mongoose errors
db.on("error", error => {
  console.log("Mongoose Error: ", error);
});

// Once logged in to the db through mongoose, log a success message
db.once("open", () => {
  console.log("Mongoose connection successful.");
});

// -------------------------- Listen -----------------------------

// Start the API server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("App listening on PORT " + PORT);
});
```

Let me know if you have errors or if this isn't solving the problem!

Comment: Ok I got this to work - and the dom is receiving the `index.html` file, but then React isn't kicking in...? I added a react CDN in the `index` file, but React still won't load. Thoughts?

Comment: @IsraelPeck it doesn't look like your `index.html` file is calling any custom scripts to run `react`. You'll need to add some a `<script>` tag to your index below where you import react from the CDN - and render your app into the `<div id="root">` element.

Comment: What do you mean a `"custom script"` to run `react`? Separate from the CDN? Do you have an example?